# Rails set a record as read only based on a column value in the record

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a Rails application with a table called Events.  When the event is created, a field called maxsynch is set to "n".  We use Mule to pull those events into another application.  When it pulls one of the events, it sets the maxsynch to "s".

I'm wondering if I can set the records with maxsynch = "s" to read only.

I found the following code on StackOverflow:

```
 def create_or_update
  raise ReadOnlyRecord if readonly?
  result = new_record? ? create : update
  result != false
 end

 def readonly?
  new_record? ? false : true
 end
```

This is supposed to set a record as read-only after it is created (I think). I wanted to start testing by trying this first.  Then change the code to define the readonly? as maxsynch = "s".

When I put that code into my events controller and try to update an event, I get the following error:

```
uninitialized constant Event::ReadOnlyRecord
```

From the line of code:

```
     raise ReadOnlyRecord if readonly?
```

Comment: You may want to do that in a validation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to raise a particular kind of exception, you should create the corresponding exception/error class :

```
class ReadOnlyRecord < Exception

end
```

Check http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Exception.html